# How to add dropdown in column of excel sheet programmatically with Excel.Package?

Tags: asp.net

How to add drop down list / combo box in a particular column when creating excel sheet with the help of ExcelPackage dll.

Please Reply .......

Regards,
Girish

Answer (score 0):

A Link for you...hope this will help:

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb257110.aspx)

**Edit:**
A small example

[Example](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20021012.asp)

Comment: Isn't simply the ComboBox...and ComboBoxItem you are asking for?

Comment: I am creating a excel sheet with ExcelPackage.dll.
& now want some particular value as a drop down select in some particular column. So that after creating Excel user can manually open the Excel & can set value from drop down list.

Comment: Did you get an answer fot this?  If so could you maybe share some code with me?